# convert list of number to list of VARCHAR2 in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Good day! I need convert (123456789012, 091234567812, 981234567890) to ('123456789012', '091234567812', '981234567890') for use it in SELECT * from table where field in ('123456789012', '091234567812', '981234567890'). Solution via native SQL or PL/SQL will suit any. Could you help me?

I not tried anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it'll work as you expected. You should actually split that string (a *column*) into rows; something like this:

```
with temp (col) as
  (select '123456789012, 091234567812, 981234567890' from dual)
select *
from your_table
where field in (select trim(regexp_substr(col, '[^,]+', 1, level))
                from temp
                connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ',') + 1
               )
```

Comment: This suitable for next job!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the numbers (without quoting them) and look for sub-string matches (with the surrounding delimiter characters so that you match entire terms):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ', ' || '123456789012, 091234567812, 981234567890' || ', '
         LIKE '%, ' || field || ', %';
```